# React Native Picker cant send data value to debugger

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, frontend, picker

im new in react native, in this project i want to use picker for sending data to debugger with this code:

note: `form` & `form.TandaPengenal` from reducer that i made

```
const Register = ({navigation}) => {
  const {form} = useSelector((state) => state.RegisterReducer);
  const dispacth = useDispatch();

  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState("java");

  const onInputChange = (value, inputType) => {
    dispacth(setForm(inputType, value));
  };

  const sendData = () => {
    console.log('data yang di kirim: ', form);
  };
  return (
      <View style={styles.picker}>
        <Picker
          selectedValue={selectedValue}
          value={form.tandaPengenal}
          style={{height: 28, width: 330}}
          onValueChange={(value) => onInputChange(value, 'tandaPengenal'),(itemValue, itemIndex) => setSelectedValue(itemValue)}>
          <Picker.Item label="Kartu Pelajar" value="Kartu Pelajar" />
          <Picker.Item label="Kitas" value="Kitas" />
          <Picker.Item label="KTP" value="KTP" />
          <Picker.Item label="NPWP" value="NPWP" />
          <Picker.Item label="Passport" value="Passport" />
          <Picker.Item label="SIM" value="SIM" />
          <Picker.Item label="SIUP" value="SIUP" />
        </Picker>
      </View>

      <Button title="Daftar" onPress={sendData} />
     
  );
};
```

from this code i cant get the value from picker that i pick, But when i use this code:

```
const Register = ({navigation}) => {
  const {form} = useSelector((state) => state.RegisterReducer);
  const dispacth = useDispatch();

  const onInputChange = (value, inputType) => {
    dispacth(setForm(inputType, value));
  };

  const sendData = () => {
    console.log('data yang di kirim: ', form);
  };
  return (
      <View style={styles.picker}>
        <Picker
          selectedValue={selectedValue}
          value={form.tandaPengenal}
          style={{height: 28, width: 330}}
          onValueChange={(value) => onInputChange(value, 'tandaPengenal')}>
          <Picker.Item label="Kartu Pelajar" value="Kartu Pelajar" />
          <Picker.Item label="Kitas" value="Kitas" />
          <Picker.Item label="KTP" value="KTP" />
          <Picker.Item label="NPWP" value="NPWP" />
          <Picker.Item label="Passport" value="Passport" />
          <Picker.Item label="SIM" value="SIM" />
          <Picker.Item label="SIUP" value="SIUP" />
        </Picker>
      </View>

      <Button title="Daftar" onPress={sendData} />
     
  );
};
```

i can get the data but the picker only show 1 value.

how can i get the value from picker to debugger and it show all picker value?